# Redirect user to my app from browser

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, openurl

In my app I have loaded tabbar controller when app launch. On that I am presenting login page and when user logged in I am dismissing that login page. So when ever app starts there will be login page. Now In that login page I have one button . Thar button present registration page on login page. And whenever user complete reg. process I simply dismissing only reeg. page from login page. Now In my app. I am sending one mail to user which contains link that will redirect user to my app reg. page. So when user will redirect I want to show him directly reg. page on login page. For that I have written code but It is showing only login page and when I log some value of reg. page it is also print that value but only showing loging page.  If I first dismiss loging page and then present reg. page on tabbar then it is working fine but as I told before I want to redirect user to login page after reg. page. My code is.::

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
NSString *urlString=[url absoluteString];
NSLog(@"string%@",urlString);
NSRange r = [urlString rangeOfString:@"myApp" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if(r.location != NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"founddddd");
    NSLog(@"MyApp url %@",url);
    //NSString *str=[url valueForKey:@"email"];
    NSArray *query = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[query count]];
    for(NSString *parameter in query)
    {
        NSArray *kv = [parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [parameters setObject:[kv count] > 1 ? [[kv objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] : [NSNull null]
                       forKey:[[kv objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", parameters);



    RegistrationViewController *RegistrationVC=[[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NSLog(@"q = %@", [parameters objectForKey:@"email"]);

      RegistrationVC.fromBrowser=TRUE;
   [loginVC presentViewController:RegistrationVC animated:NO completion:^{
         NSLog(@"txtemail %@ value%@",RegistrationVC.txtEmail,RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text);
       RegistrationVC.txtEmail.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
       RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text=[parameters objectForKey:@"email"];
       RegistrationVC.btnServiceProvider.hidden=YES;
       RegistrationVC.lbl_create.hidden=YES;

    }];


    return YES;

}
  return NO;
  }
```

Here loginVC I am allocation at the time when I am presenting login page on my tabbar.And I am getting this in my log::

```
Warning: Attempt to present <RegistrationViewController: 0xd8699c0> on <LoginViewController: 0xdd51a00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: I guess this is not right approach, there are more better ways to authenticate user

Comment: can you suggest me???

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with this

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
NSString *urlString=[url absoluteString];
NSLog(@"string%@",urlString);
NSRange r = [urlString rangeOfString:@"myApp" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

if(r.location != NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"founddddd");
    NSLog(@"MyApp url %@",url);
    //NSString *str=[url valueForKey:@"email"];
    NSArray *query = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[query count]];
    for(NSString *parameter in query)
    {
        NSArray *kv = [parameter componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        [parameters setObject:[kv count] > 1 ? [[kv objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] : [NSNull null]
                       forKey:[[kv objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Parameters: %@", parameters);



   [self performSelector:@selector(gooRegestraction) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];

    return YES;

}
  return NO;
  }

-(void)gooRegestraction{

 RegistrationViewController *RegistrationVC=[[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NSLog(@"q = %@", [parameters objectForKey:@"email"]);

      RegistrationVC.fromBrowser=TRUE;
   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:RegistrationVC animated:YES completion:^{
    RegistrationVC.txtEmail.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    RegistrationVC.txtEmail.text=[parameters objectForKey:@"email"];
    RegistrationVC.btnServiceProvider.hidden=YES;
    RegistrationVC.lbl_create.hidden=YES;

}];

}
```

Comment: I am not getting any error...just its show me login page not the reg. page

Comment: call method after some delay

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44935/discussion-between-sunny-shah-and-vivek)